# store multiple selection from select picker in an array

Tags: php, jquery, select, laravel-4, picker

I have a laravel select using select picker for multiple selection.

```
{{ Form::select('spokenLanguages[]', $motherTongue, $spokenLanguages, array('class' => 'selectpicker form-control','id' => 'spoke','multiple' => true)) }}
```

$motherTongue is an array of different languages. 
I am trying to show the value of a select picker in an array using jquery.

```
var d = [];
$('#spoke :selected').each(function(i){d.push( $('#spoke :selected').val());});
$('#tdSpoken').html(d);
```

If i am selecting two languages (English, Hindi) then its looping 2 times but it shows the first selection in each loop like this,

```
EnglishEnglish
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var d = []; 
$('#spoke :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
  d[i] = $(selected).val(); 
});
```

You can get d as array of selected values.